# Get a value from gridbox to another page textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new in Asp.net. I have 2 webforms webform1.aspx and webform2.aspx. i have 2 textboxes as name and mark and labelbox as student id in webform1.aspx.. i have stored these textbox values to database and autogenerate the student id.. i i have gridbox in another page webform2.aspx. i get all the values from database to gridview box. also i have a link button in this gridbox if i click that link button in gridbox view i want automatically get the values from database to a particular textboxes in webform.aspx.. pls guide me... advance thanks friends...

Comment: Please show us your code work.

Answer (score 0):

On webForm2.aspx, you should [AutoGenerateSelectButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateselectbutton.aspx) and then listen for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
       autogenerateselectbutton="True"
       onselectedindexchanged="CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
       runat="server">
</asp:gridview>
```

CodeBehind:

```
void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;

    //Work with your selected row
    MyText.Text = "You selected " + row.Cells[2].Text + ".";

}
```